# How to pass component state in router to another router component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am now designing the `frontend` part. Here is my `Router`
`/` is the loginpage. It check the `token` in side the `localStorage`. And it has `isAuthenticated` in the `state`

`/select-teams` is feature page and before let user use it it must validate  `token` first. 
The questions are.
1. Should refresh `token` every time before `query` the `APIs`?
2. Between implement `componentWillMount` with checking `token` function every time VS pass the state. Which one is best practice? IMO read `localStorage` every time might slow down the app. However, it is easy for me to do, but it is not `DRY`
3. Suppose I want to pass `isAuthenticated` state between `Route` to another `Route`. How can I do that?

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import promise from 'redux-promise';
import LoginPage from "./components/loginPage";
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import SelectTeam from './components/select_teams';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/select-teams" component={SelectTeam}/>
          <Route path="/" component={LoginPage}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Here is my `Component`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import login_image from '../images/login_image.png';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import {getTokenAuth, refreshToken} from "../actions";
import ErrorMessage from './errorMessage';

class LoginPage extends Component {
  //1. Verify user token. If token is good.
  //1.1 Do refresh token and
  //1.2 Then put him to `select-teams` page
  //1.3 Finally set isAuthenticated: true

  //2. If token is not good. Let user login again.
  //By setting the isAuthenticated: false
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const isAuthenticated = !((token === undefined) | (token === null));
    this.state = {
      token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
      isAuthenticated,
      message: null,
      statusCode: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Enter componentWillMount');
    const token = this.state.token;
    if (token === undefined || token === null)
      this.setState((prevState) => {
        {
          isAuthenticated: false
        }
      });
    else {
      console.log('componentWillMount token is exist');
      //Refresh the token. Let backend verify it
      //Outcome is 1. It is expired and unable to refresh
      //Or 2. It is refreshed
      this.props.refreshToken(token, (res) => {
        console.log(res.status);
        if (res.status === 200) {
          //Receive new token
          localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
          this.setState((prevState) => {
            return Object.assign(prevState, {
              isAuthenticated: true,
              statusCode: res.status,
              message: res.statusText
            });
          });
          this.props.history.push('/select-teams');
        } else {
          //Token is expired and can not be able to refresh again. Force user to do login again by remove his token
          localStorage.removeItem('token');
          this.setState((prevState) => {
            return Object.assign(prevState, {
              isAuthenticated: false,
              statusCode: res.status,
              message: res.data.non_field_errors
            });
          });
        }
      })
    }
  }

  renderField(field) {
    const {meta: {touched, error}} = field;
    const className = `'form-group' ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label>{field.label}</label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type={field.type}
          placeholder={field.placeholder}
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          {touched ? error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }


  onSubmit(values) {
    console.log(values);
    this.props.getTokenAuth(values, (res) => {
      console.log(res.status);
      if (res.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token);
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return Object.assign(prevState, {
            isAuthenticated: true,
            statusCode: res.status,
            message: res.statusText
          });
        });
        this.props.history.push('/select-teams');
      } else {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          return Object.assign(prevState, {
            isAuthenticated: false,
            statusCode: res.status,
            message: res.data.non_field_errors
          });
        });
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <img src={login_image} alt="Poink Logo"/>
        <ErrorMessage
          isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
          message={this.state.message}
        />

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
          <Field
            name="userid"
            component={this.renderField}
            placeholder="User ID"
            type="text"
          />
          <Field
            name="password"
            component={this.renderField}
            placeholder="Password"
            type="password"
          />
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <a className='btn btn-primary' href="https://www.magicboxasia.com/">Sign up</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  // Validate the inputs from 'values'
  if (!values.userid) {
    errors.userid = "Enter a user ID!";
  }

  if (!values.password) {
    errors.password = "Enter your password";
  }

  return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    token: state.token,
    isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'LoginForm'
})(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {getTokenAuth, refreshToken})(LoginPage)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your react app should verify if the token is on localstore/another storage, and your backend must verify if the token is valid, because you cant verify if a token is valid without its secret.

What we have done in the company i work is a High Order Component that receives a function that checks if  the token is stored as props. If the function returns to true, we render the component, if it dosnt, it redirects to login route. The function is called `isAuthorized`.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthorized, ...otherProps }) => (
<Route
    {...otherProps}
    render={props => (
        isAuthorized() ? (<Component {...props} />) :
            (
                <Redirect to={
                    {
                        pathname: '/login',
                        state: { from: props.location },
                    }
                }
                />
            )
    )}
/>
);
```

This is our index. We import the function that tells if the user is authorized to see this route, which in this case is `hasToken`:

```
<Switch>
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" isAuthorized={hasToken} component={Home} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/list" isAuthorized={hasToken} component={List} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path="/view/:id" isAuthorized={hasToken} component={View} />
    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
</Switch>
```

Now its PrivateRoute resposability to redirect users to login if the token is not present.

Now you should look into a nice way to redirect users to login if the backend retuns 401 (unauthorized). The backend is the actual token validator. In the company i work in we use axios to do our ajax calls, and we created a axios interceptor that redirects the user to login route if the backend responses returns 401 http status code.

Comment: Please be patient. If I take up to several days to understand your answer.

Comment: I will try answer your question more directly. 

1) No, you shouldnt. You front end should only check if token is present. This is the "is authorized" for the front end. You backend is the one who should validate the token at each request. If it sees its not valid, it should return 401. You front end then should redirect to login page if it receives 401 from the backend. We did it using axios interceptors to keep it DRY.

2) Yes, at each route component (page component/container), u should see if the token is not present before render it. We used this PrivateRoute component to keep it DRY.

Comment: Please correct me if I am doing in wrong way. I am now going to promote my `<App/>` to be a `container`. And let the every `<PrivateRoute/>` follow `<App/>` state. By that I can pass the `props.location`. I think `location` is last page that user got kicked out to login page when `token` is expired. Therefore when the user fill in the `LoginForm` and success. He will be `push` to last known logged in page again.

Comment: I will ask again in the very details of my components. Thank you very much.